# JAVA (Newbie Q) local variable

Tags: java, variables, local

Why I am not allowed to initiate program, it says : delete phrase token. Sorry for noob Q (First Q in this forum)

```
public class Pirma {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] wordlistOne = {"ziaurus", "grazus", "baisus", "fainas"};
    String[] wordlistTwo = {"afigienas", "negeras", "idomus", "juokingas"};
    String[] wordlistThree = {"nekoks", "neidomus", "lameris", "kietas"};

    int oneLength = wordlistOne.length;
    int twoLength = wordlistTwo.length;
    int threeLength = wordlistThree.length;

    int rand1 = (int) (Math.random() * oneLength);
    int rand2 = (int) (Math.random() * twoLength);
    int rand3 = (int) (Math.random() * threeLength);

    ***String phrase*** = wordlistOne[rand1] + " " + wordlistTwo[rand2] + " " + wordlistThree[rand3];
    System.out.println("What we need is" + " " ***phrase***);
}
}
```

Comment: This is enough info for us to figure out how to answer your question, but in the future when you have problems like this, you should always tell us *exactly* what the error says.

Answer (score 5):

You forgot a `+` between `" "` and `phrase`.

Answer (score 3):

```
***String phrase*** = wordlistOne[rand1] + " " + 
        wordlistTwo[rand2] + " " + wordlistThree[rand3];
System.out.println("What we need is" + " " ***phrase***);
```

isn't valid on account of all of these asterisks. You'll want to remove them and add a `+` to be:

```
String phrase = wordlistOne[rand1] + " " + wordlistTwo[rand2] + " " + wordlistThree[rand3];
    System.out.println("What we need is" + " " + phrase);
```

Edit: reading comments, it seems that the asterisks are mainly for emphasis. Your error is still the missing `+` between `" "` and `phrase`.

Comment: The asterisks are probably just an attempt to highlight, markdown style. but that't possible in the code block.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
    String phrase = wordlistOne[rand1] + " " + wordlistTwo[rand2] + " " + wordlistThree[rand3];
    System.out.println("What we need is " + phrase);
```